# Accessibility not working properly on UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionviewcell, uipagecontrol, uiaccessibility

in my app i have a `UICollectionView` and `UIPageControl` inside `UITableViewCell`. `UICollectionView` has three different kind of `cells` and each cell covers the full width of iPhone. With accessibility on we are facing a problem when the focus is on `UIPageControl` and we try to adjust its value by swiping up and down and then traverse back to the cell it loses its focus and takes us to some different cell instead of taking control to the cell which we have changed using `UIPageControl`.
We are changing the cell on value change event of UIPageControl.

Comment: What accessibility methods are you calling to do this, show the code

Comment: please share some code

Comment: @IBAction func pageControlValueChanged(sender: UIPageControl) {
        collectionView!.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: sender.currentPage, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: false)
        self.pageControl!.currentPage = sender.currentPage
    }

Comment: I tried throwing notifications like LayoutChanged and ScreenChanged but nothing worked.

Comment: how you solved this issue? I faced the same thing... and cant manage it...

Comment: @Melany Its not resolved we observed the same behavior in iOS native stocks app where they have page control. So, its still persistent in our app. Thanks.

Comment: @IOSCODER,  I solved this issue with adding additional view on tableViewCell, and then on it added UICollectionView (in my case it was GMGridView , but its the same). and than array with accessibility from UICollectionView i assigned to the AccessibiltyElements of this view. In this case this additional view became container for uicollectionView.  And after that it works correctly, you can try this solution.you can try it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814980/uiaccessibility-in-gridview-doesnt-see-new-cells?noredirect=1#comment65001872_38814980